# Warnings in match.names quantstrat

Tags: r, warnings, match, quantstrat

I get some warnings when running my quantstrat code, for example one of them is:
`Warning messages:
1: In match.names(columns, colnames(data)) :
  all columns not located in Close SMA50 for AGG.Open AGG.High AGG.Low AGG.Close AGG.Volume AGG.Adjusted AGG.Rank SMA.SMA50 Cl.gt.SMA50`

My code is:

```
library(quantstrat)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

Sys.setenv(TZ="UTC")

currency("USD")
symbols <- c("XLY", "XLP", "XLE", "AGG", "IVV")
stock(symbols, currency="USD")

# get data for the symbols
getSymbols(symbols, from="2005-01-01", to="2012-12-31")

# create an xts object of monthly adjusted close prices
symbols.close <- monthlyPrices(symbols)

# create an xts object of the symbol ranks
sym.rank <- applyRank(x=symbols.close, rankFun=ave3ROC, n=c(2, 4, 6))


# this is an important step in naming the columns, e.g. XLY.Rank
# the "Rank" column is used as the trade signal (similar to an indicator)
# in the qstratRank function
colnames(sym.rank) <- gsub(".Close", ".Rank", colnames(sym.rank))

# ensure the order of order symbols is equal to the order of columns 
# in symbols.close
stopifnot(all.equal(gsub(".Close", "", colnames(symbols.close)), symbols))

# bind the rank column to the appropriate symbol market data
# loop through symbols, convert the data to monthly and cbind the data
# to the rank
for(i in 1:length(symbols)) {
  x <- get(symbols[i])
  x <- to.weekly(x,indexAt='lastof',drop.time=TRUE)
  indexFormat(x) <- '%Y-%m-%d'
  colnames(x) <- gsub("x",symbols[i],colnames(x))
  x <- cbind(x, sym.rank[,i])
  assign(symbols[i],x)
}

bt <- qstratRank(symbols=symbols, init.equity=100000, top.N=1,
                 max.size=1000, max.levels=1)
```

And `qstratRank` function is:

```
qstratRank <- function(symbols, init.equity=100000, top.N=1, 
                       max.size=1000, max.levels=1) {
  # The qstratRank function uses the quantstrat framework to backtest a
  # ranking or relative strength strategy
  #
  # args
  # symbols     : character vector of symbols
  # init.equity : initial equity
  # top.N       : trade the top N ranked assets
  # max.size    : maximum position size
  # max.levels  : maximum levels to scale in a trade
  # max.size and max.levels are passed to addPosLimit
  #
  # return value
  # returns a list: end.eq, returns, book, stats

  # remove variables
  suppressWarnings(rm("order_book.Rank", pos=.strategy))
  suppressWarnings(rm("account.Rank", "portfolio.Rank", pos=.blotter))
  suppressWarnings(rm("account.st", "port.st", "stock.str", "stratRank",
                      "initDate", "initEq", 'start_t', 'end_t'))


  # set initial variables
  initDate <- "1900-01-01"
  initEq <- init.equity
  port.st <- "Rank"
  account.st <- "Rank"

  # trade the top "N" ranked symbols
  N <- top.N

  # initialize quantstrat objects
  initPortf(port.st, symbols=symbols, initDate=initDate)
  initAcct(account.st, portfolios=port.st, initDate=initDate,initEq=initEq)
  initOrders(portfolio=port.st, initDate=initDate)

  # initialize a strategy object
  stratRank <- strategy("Rank")

  # there are two signals
  # the first signal is when Rank is less than or equal to N
  # (i.e. trades the #1 ranked symbol if N=1)

  stratRank <- add.indicator(strategy=stratRank, name="SMA", 
                         arguments=list(x = quote(Cl(mktdata)), n=50), label="SMA50")

  stratRank <- add.signal(stratRank, name="sigComparison", 
           arguments=list(columns=c("Close", "SMA50"), relationship="gt"), label="Cl.gt.SMA50")

  stratRank <- add.signal(stratRank, name="sigComparison", 
                          arguments=list(columns=c("Close", "SMA50"), relationship="lt"), label="Cl.lt.SMA50")

  stratRank <- add.signal(strategy=stratRank, name="sigThreshold", 
                          arguments=list(threshold=N, column="Rank", 
                                         relationship="lte", cross=FALSE), 
                          label="Rank.lte.N")

  # the second signal is when Rank is greter than or equal to N
  # (i.e. trades the #1 ranked symbol if N=1)
  stratRank <- add.signal(strategy=stratRank, name="sigThreshold", 
                          arguments=list(threshold=N, column="Rank", 
                                         relationship="gt", cross=FALSE), 
                          label="Rank.gt.N")



  # add buy rule
  stratRank <- add.rule(strategy=stratRank, name='ruleSignal', 
                        arguments = list(sigcol="Cl.lt.SMA50", sigval=TRUE, 
                                         orderqty=max.size, ordertype='market', 
                                         orderside='long', pricemethod='market', 
                                         replace=FALSE, osFUN=osMaxPos), 
                        type='enter', path.dep=TRUE)



  stratRank <- add.rule(strategy=stratRank, name='ruleSignal', 
                        arguments = list(sigcol="Rank.lte.N", sigval=TRUE, 
                                         orderqty=max.size, ordertype='market', 
                                         orderside='long', pricemethod='market', 
                                         replace=FALSE, osFUN=osMaxPos), 
                        type='enter', path.dep=TRUE)

  # add exit rule
#   stratRank <- add.rule(strategy=stratRank, name='ruleSignal', 
#                         arguments = list(sigcol="Cl.lt.SMA50", sigval=TRUE, 
#                                          orderqty="all", ordertype='market', 
#                                          orderside='long', pricemethod='market', 
#                                          replace=FALSE, osFUN=osMaxPos), 
#                         type='exit', path.dep=TRUE)
#   

  stratRank <- add.rule(strategy = stratRank, name='ruleSignal', 
                        arguments = list(sigcol="Rank.gt.N", sigval=TRUE, 
                                         orderqty='all', ordertype='market', 
                                         orderside='long', pricemethod='market', 
                                         replace=FALSE), 
                        type='exit', path.dep=TRUE)

  #set max position size and levels
  for(symbol in symbols){ addPosLimit(port.st, symbol, initDate, max.size, max.levels) }

  print("setup completed")

  # apply the strategy to the portfolio
  start_t <- Sys.time()
  out <- try(applyStrategy(strategy=stratRank, portfolios=port.st))
  end_t <- Sys.time()
  print(end_t-start_t)

  # update Portfolio
  start_t <- Sys.time()
  updatePortf(Portfolio=port.st, Dates=paste('::', as.Date(Sys.time()), sep=''))
  end_t <- Sys.time()
  print("trade blotter portfolio update:")
  print(end_t - start_t)

  # update account
  updateAcct(account.st)

  # update ending equity
  updateEndEq(account.st)

  # get ending equity
  eq <- getEndEq(account.st, Sys.Date()) + initEq

  # view order book to confirm trades
  order.book <- getOrderBook(port.st)

  # get trade statistics
  stats <- tradeStats(port.st)

  # portfolio returns
  ret1 <- PortfReturns(port.st)
  ret1$total <- rowSums(ret1, na.rm=TRUE)

  return(list(end.eq=eq, returns=ret1, book=order.book, stats=stats))
}
```

And the functions I use are:

```
##### monthlyAd function #####
monthlyAd <- function(x){
  # Converts daily data to monthly and returns only the monthly close 
  # Note: only used with Yahoo Finance data so far
  # Thanks to Joshua Ulrich for the Monthly Ad function
  # 
  # args:
  #   x = daily price data from Yahoo Finance
  #
  # Returns:
  #   xts object with the monthly adjusted close prices

  sym <- sub("\\..*$", "", names(x)[1])
  Cl(to.weekly(x, indexAt = 'lastof', drop.time = TRUE, name = sym))
}

##### monthlyReturns function #####
monthlyReturns <- function(symbols) {
  # The function takes a character vector of symbols loaded into
  # the environment and returns an xts object of simple returns
  # Currently this is only for prepping monthly data

  # symbols : character vector of symbols

  ROC(x = monthlyPrices(symbols), n = 1, type = "discrete", na.pad = TRUE)
}

##### monthlyPrices function #####
monthlyPrices <- function(symbols) {
  # The function takes a character vector of symbols loaded into
  # the environment and returns an xts object of Adjusted close prices
  # Currently this is only for prepping monthly data

  # symbols         : character vector of symbols
  # list.sym        : list of symbols with market data

  list.sym <- list()
  for(i in 1:length(symbols)) {
    list.sym[[symbols[i]]] <- get(symbols[i])
  }

  do.call(merge, lapply(list.sym, monthlyAd))
}

# Functions for ways to rank assets based on rate of change
# TODO - add functions to rank based on other factors

# The functions defined below depend on functions in the xts and TTR packages
# library(TTR)

##### applyRank #####
applyRank <- function(x, rankFun, ...) {
  # symbols : character vector of symbols
  # rankFun : function that returns the rank
  # rankFun should be ave3ROC, weightAve3ROC, strengthROC, strengthAve3ROC,
  # etfReplayRank, or strengthSMA.
  # x       : xts object of prices
  # ...     : arguments to rankFun

  FUN <- match.fun(rankFun)
  FUN(x, ...)
}

##### symbolRank #####
symbolRank <- function(symbols, rank.obj) {
  # loop through symbols
  # convert the market data to monthly periodicity 
  # cbind the appropriate column from rank.obj to the market data
  # makes the assumption that the order symbols and rank.obj are equal

  # symbols  : character vector of symbols
  # rank.obj : xts object of ranks of each symbol

  for(i in 1:length(symbols)) {
    x <- get(symbols[i])
    x <- to.monthly(x,indexAt='lastof',drop.time=TRUE)
    indexFormat(x) <- '%Y-%m-%d'
    colnames(x) <- gsub("x", symbols[i], colnames(x))
    x <- cbind(x, rank.obj[,i])
    assign(symbols[i],x)
  }
}

##### rowRank #####
rowRank <- function(x){
  # Computes the rank of an xts object of ranking factors
  # ranking factors are the factors that are ranked (i.e. asset returns)
  #
  #  x : xts object of ranking factors
  #
  #   Returns an xts object with ranks
  #   For ranking asset returns, the asset with the greatest return
  #   receives a  rank of 1

  as.xts(t(apply(-x, 1, rank, na.last = "keep")))
}

#Use the supplied TTR::ROC function for a straight ROC computation

##### ave3ROC #####
ave3ROC <- function(x, n=c(1, 3, 6)){
  # Computes the average rate of change based on averaging 3 periods
  #
  #  x   : xts object of prices
  #  n   : vector of periods to use n = (period1, period2, period3)
  #  ave : xts object of asset rate of change by averaging 3 periods

  roc1 <- ROC(x, n = n[1], type = "discrete")
  roc2 <- ROC(x, n = n[2], type = "discrete")
  roc3 <- ROC(x, n = n[3], type = "discrete")
  ave <- (roc1 + roc2 + roc3)/3
  rowRank(ave)
}
```

So the problem seems to be in SMA, any ideas?
Best Regards

Comment: Are you using the latest TTR from R-Forge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just faced that problem. The error is not in the `SMA` function, I believe it's related to your column names (see the `label` parameter of `add.indicator` and the `column` parameter of `add.signal`) in your indicators and signals. Try debugging the error after your `add.indicator` and `add.signal` lines in your `qstratRank` function by using, `temp <- applyIndicators(strategy = stratRank, mktdata = XLY)` and then `applySignals(strategy = stratRank, mktdata = temp)`. The error should be there. I fixed it by changing the `label` parameter of my `add.indicator` calls. I don't know what are the column names of your indicator, but it looks like it's because of `arguments=list(columns=c("Close", "SMA50")` in your signals.